# python inside vim to obtain file list from current directory

Tags: python, vim

How would I use python script to communicate with vim..

Using ultisnips plugin, I have option to include shell script or python script inside snippet definition, using `!p` for python for example. Now, what I am trying to do is to get list of files in current directory and put them in between `<files>` tag. something like this.

snippet lsf

```
!p 
import glob
cwd = vim.eval("getcwd()")  # or maybe vim.eval("expand('%:h')")
snip.rv = "\n".join([ "\t<files>%s</files>" % file for file in glob(cwd + "/*")])
```

endsnippet

Dont pay attention to first and last lines as they are syntax for creating a snippet using ultisnips, what counts is the whole script I have in syntax highlighting.

but it throws errors. where I might be wrong, any suggestion?

Comment: "/home/branchito/.vim/bundle/ultisnips/plugin/UltiSnips/text_objects/_ snippet_instance.py", line 70, in update_textobjects  
    if obj._update(done, not_done):
  File "/home/branchito/.vim/bundle/ultisnips/plugin/UltiSnips/text_objects/_python_code.py", line 216, in _update  
    compatible_exec(self._code, self._globals, local_d)
  File "/home/branchito/.vim/bundle/ultisnips/plugin/UltiSnips/compatibility_py2.py", line 12, in compatible_exec  
    exec code in gglobals, glocals
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: it seems that i cannot communicate vim this way..

Comment: You don’t need `vim.eval('getcwd()')`, regular `os.getcwd()` works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have simply imported the glob module not the glob function and have tried calling the module as a function.

```
!p 
from glob import glob #Change this line as shown
cwd = vim.eval("getcwd()")  # or maybe vim.eval("expand('%:h')")
snip.rv = "\n".join([ "\t<files>%s</files>" % file for file in glob(cwd + "/*")])
```

This is at least the initial problem.

Comment: now how would i make the script give me files and folders separately..

so i would have: 
      <files>fname</files>  

and then :
      <folder>foldername</folder>  

also i would like to strip ./ from the beginning of file name listing.. cant see those options in glob manual of python? thanks

Comment: you could use os.walk

Comment: for root, dirs, files in os.walk(cwd, topdown=True):    
 
    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in excludes]  
    for pat in includes:  
        for f in fnmatch.filter(files, pat):  
            print os.path.join(root, f)  

tried this but it gives empty string

Comment: includes = ['*.php', '*.ini']  
excludes = []

Comment: maybe all 'for in' has to be in that snip.rv line?